# Where does the value in my function come from?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently working my way through the functional JavaScript exercise at http://nodeschool.io.

I have the following exercise:

> Return a function that takes a list of valid users, and returns a function that returns true if all of the supplied users exist in the original list of users.
>
> You only need to check that the ids match.

Example:

```
var goodUsers = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
];

// `checkUsersValid` is the function you'll define

var testAllValid = checkUsersValid(goodUsers);

testAllValid([
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 1 }
]);

// => true

testAllValid([
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 1 }
]);

// => false
```

Arguments:

- `goodUsers`: a list of valid users

> Use `array.some` and `array.every` to check whether every user passed to your returned function exists in the array passed to the exported function.

The answer to the task is:

```
function checkUsersValid(goodUsers) {
    return function (submittedUsers) {
        return submittedUsers.every(function (submittedUser) {
            return goodUsers.some(function (goodUser) {
                return submittedUser.id === goodUser.id;
            });
        });
    };
}

module.exports = checkUsersValid;
```

However, I do not understand where the values for `submittedUsers` is coming from given that:

```
var testAllValid = checkUsersValid(goodUsers);
```

And that the function is called with:

```
testAllValid([
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 1 }
]);

// => true
```

Shouldn't that above equate to:

```
checkUsersValid([
    {id:2},
    {id:1}
]);
```

In this case where am i getting the values for `submittedUsers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that:

```
function checkUsersValid(goodUsers) {
    return function (submittedUsers) {
        return submittedUsers.every(function (submittedUser) {
            return goodUsers.some(function (goodUser) {
                return submittedUser.id === goodUser.id;
            });
        });
    };
}
```

We also know that:

```
var goodUsers = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
];

var testAllValid = checkUsersValid(goodUsers);
```

Hence by substitution:

```
var goodUsers = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
];

var testAllValid = function (submittedUsers) {
    return submittedUsers.every(function (submittedUser) {
        return goodUsers.some(function (goodUser) {
            return submittedUser.id === goodUser.id;
        });
    });
};
```

Finally, we call:

```
testAllValid([
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 1 }
]);
```

What does it evaluate to?

```
var goodUsers = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
];

var submittedUsers = [
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 1 }
];

// it evaluates to:

submittedUsers.every(function (submittedUser) {
    return goodUsers.some(function (goodUser) {
        return submittedUser.id === goodUser.id;
    });
});
```

If you evaluate it you'll see that every `submittedUser` is also a `goodUser`. Hence the answer is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `checkUsersValid` just creates a function and returns the created function. Invoking it with any input, will get you another function. So,

```
checkUsersValid([
    {id:2},
    {id:1}
]);
```

will be returning you another function. Now, if you think about what `checkUsersValid` does, it accepts a list of whitelisted users and returns a function which checks if the list of users to be validated is in the whitelisted users.

So, `checkUsersValid` creates a function to check the whitelisted users and `testAllValid` is the function which does the actual validation. They both are doing different tasks.

Now, you might be wondering why would we do it like this, instead of doing like

```
testAllValid(listOfValidUsers, listOfUsersToBeValidated);
```

If `listOfValidUsers` is a static list, and you are going to use `testAllValid` in multiple places (even in places where `listOfValidUsers` will not be in scope), then you need to figure out a way to make `listOfValidUsers` available for `testAllValid`. Instead, we create a new function with `checkUsersValid`, which can remember the `listOfValidUsers` (because of the closure property), you just need to make sure that the function object is available everywhere. That would make the code less cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

There are two level of closures here. In the first level you submit all the valid users (i.e. `goodUsers`) and it returns a `function` (i.e., `testAllValid`).

The `testAllValid` function is also a closure which takes a parameter (i.e., `submittedUsers`)  and returns the final result.

please read [javascript closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) for detail